# SQL Syntax Error whilst creating a table

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have recently started learning SQL, I can't determine what is causing my syntax error (see below):

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    user_id smallint not null auto_increment,
    username varchar(50) unique,
    password varchar(41),
    dob date,
    session_id varchar not null,
    cookie varchar not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
    CONSTRAINT dob_valid CHECK(dob < current_date())
);
```

This does work when all varchar fields have a predefined length. Do all fields of type varchar require a size parameter?

I am sorry if this problem seems very simple.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: it says what is causing syntax error. in the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes all varchar require a max size.

Comment: ah thank you, is this the same for the char data type. What should you do if you do not know the what the size of this field will be?

Comment: answered by own question thanks to alex martelli, a very helpful post!

Answer (score 1):

As [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/char.html) say,

> The CHAR and VARCHAR types are
>   declared with a length that indicates
>   the maximum number of characters you
>   want to store.

Another way of checking this (that the length is *not* optional): check the `data_type` production in the relevant docs's page on [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/create-table.html) (for `CREATE TABLE`) and you'll see, in part:

```
 VARCHAR(length)
      [CHARACTER SET charset_name] [COLLATE collation_name]
```

See?  the `(length)` part is **not** within square brackets in this syntax description: that means it's **not** optional, but mandatory (the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATE` parts *are* optional, so they're within square brackets).

I'm explaining this technique for reading the docs at length, because, while learning the specific syntax for this very specific use case is of course important, learning to read the manuals and find answers to your questions (syntax and otherwise) in a very speedy manner is even more important, and will increase your SQL productivity enormously.